# How to control FLV Playback in flash with Action Script?

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs4, flvplayback

How to control FLV Playback in flash with Action Script? I want to play Video in my webpage similar to YouTube. I have done it with automatic play but I want it when you press play button, then play and pause, volume, next & back as well.

Comment: Drag your video intro Flash CS4 and there should an option to use the FLVPlayback. Choose your skin (with the functionality you need(play-pause/volume/etc.) and carry on making changes as needed. See the [Getting Started guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/flvplayback_component.html). For more details on the FLVPlayback API have a look at ["Controlling web video with AS3 FLVPlayback programming"](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html) and the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of tutorials on this subject on the web (example: [gotoAndLearn](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/))

Basically you just create a Video object to which you attach a NetStream then you perform your play, pause, stop and seek operations on the NetStream which is really straightforward.

Take a look at the AS3 documentation on the videoclass also, it helped me a lot.